# golang 1.19.2 internal pkg imports

Tags: go

if I have the following proj structure:

```
  src/github.com/proj

  src/github.com/proj/a

  src/github.com/proj/b
```

and a file in pkg a references a value in pkg b.  What should this import look like in the pkg a file?

example: pkg a foo.go

```
import 
(
 github.com/proj/b //if this then I would need a go.mod entry
 proj/b //no go.mod entry

)

func fooFunc() {
 return b.Value
}
```

Comment: [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code) specifically covers creating and using multiple packages within a module. You don't need a `go.mod` entry to import something from the same module. Import paths are always the full path regardless of which module the package resides.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following:

- Your project is in a single repository on Github (github.com/user/proj), not multiple repositories as implied by the question.
- Your project has a single go.mod at the root of the project with module path github.com/user/proj.
- The files in directory b use `package b` as the package statement.

Use this import:

```
package a

import (
 "github.com/user/proj/b"
)

func fooFunc() {
 return b.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following project structure where `.` is your project root folder:

```
.
├── api
│   └── api.go
├── database
│   └── database.go
├── go.mod
└── main.go
```

And the source code file contents:

**./go.mod**

```golang
module github.com/myproj

go 1.20
```

**./main.go**

```golang
package main

import "github.com/myproj/api"

func main() {
    api.Create()
}
```

**./api/api.go**

```golang
package api

import "github.com/myproj/database"

func Create() {
    database.Create()
}
```

**./database/database.go**

```golang
package database

import "fmt"

func Create() {
    fmt.Println("OK")
}
```

Go will automatically interpret your internal packages as dependencies. From the root you run:

```
go run .
```

Note that you must make variables and functions public with a upper case first letter in order for external inner packages to have access to it.

```golang
func MyPublicFunction(){}

func myPrivateFunction(){}
```